# Adding an item to a combo box using an event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, event-handling

I am trying to add a new item to a combo box using an event handler in the form of a button click. However,  I cannot get the combobox to update using the class I have created. The class takes in strings and int's from the event handler `add_menu_item_click` my events and class are bellow:

```
private void add_menu_item_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new_combobox_item item = new new_combobox_item();
    item.item_name = new_food.Text;
    item.price = int.Parse(food_price.Text);
    Menu.item.Add(item);
    //MessageBox.Show((menulist.SelectedItem as new_combobox_item).Value.ToString());
}
```

the class it uses to store the data:

```
public class new_combobox_item
{
  private string _item_name;
  private Boolean _vegitarian;
  private int _price;
  public string item_name
  {
      get
      {
          return _item_name;
      }
      set
      {
          _item_name = value;
      }
  }

  public Boolean vegitarian
  {
      get
      {
          return _vegitarian;
      }
      set
      {
          _vegitarian = value;
      }
  }

   public int price
   {
       get
       {
           return _price;
       }
       set
       {
           _price = value;
       }
   }
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return _item_name;
   }
```

and the combo box i am trying to update:

```
    private void ComboBox_MenuLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> Menu_item = new List<String>();
        Menu_item.Add("mac and cheese");
        Menu_item.Add("Veggie Burger");
        Menu_item.Add("Lasagne");
        //Menu_item.Add(new_combobox_item.item_name);
        //combobox reference
        var menulist = sender as ComboBox;
        //assigns items to the list
        menulist.ItemsSource = Menu_item;
        //item selected
        menulist.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

any help/advice would be appreciated many thanks.

Comment: What is "Menu" - the name of your combobox? If so, that's an odd thing to name it. That is what you are adding the item to:
Menu.item.Add(item);

Comment: Agreed with @B.ClayShannon. Your event handler for the MenuLoaded event seems to indicate that your combo box control's name is ComboBox. Are you sure you're referencing the right control?

Comment: Thats my mistake i was messing with the code and forgot to change it back to: menu_item.add(item);